# PyGTK - grid_lines missing?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

For some reason I'm getting 'no attribute' errors when trying to get or set grid lines when using PyGTK:

```
import gtk
t = gtk.TreeView()
print t.get_grid_lines()
```

Gives:

```
'AttributeError: 'gtk.TreeView' object has no attribute 'get_grid_lines'
```

Here is the relevant documentation entry: http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeview.html#method-gtktreeview--get-grid-lines

And my pyGTK version is 2.4.1 and my gtk version is 2.4.9 which leaves me with no clue as to why I can't get at this function when everything else works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked to says that the function is only available in pyGTK 2.10 or later so your version is too old to have it.

Comment: Yes, you have to forget the rules of mathematics when comparing version numbers.